# pasar datos de un toast a un campo de texto

Tags: android-studio

Hola quiero pasar el datos que me muestra un toast a un textview lo que pasa es que  estoy utilizando un DialogFragment con selección multipliple y cuando seleccione un valor me los muestre en un textview.

en esta parte del codigo es donde quiero pasar el dato toas a textview

```html
 builder.setTitle("Estado Civil")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity(),
                                "Seleccionaste: " + items[which],
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                })
```

```html
package com.herprogramacion.dialogpers.dialogos;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragmento con un diálogo que muestra radio buttons
 */
public class ListRadioDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public ListRadioDialog() {
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return createRadioListDialog();
    }

    /**
     * Crea un diálogo con una lista de radios
     *
     * @return Diálogo
     */
    public AlertDialog createRadioListDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        final CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[3];

        items[0] = "Soltero/a";
        items[1] = "Casado/a";
        items[2] = "Divorciado/a";

        builder.setTitle("Estado Civil")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity(),
                                "Seleccionaste: " + items[which],
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                })

        .setPositiveButton("ACEPTAR",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });


        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Comment: para poder darte una mejor respuesta necesitamos ver tu código. Te recomiendo veas la sección de [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) de la comunidad de StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

No se puede tomar un valor de un `Toast`, lo que debes realizar es tomar el mismo valor que muestras en el `Toast`

Declara una variable de clase:

```
private String valorSeleccionado = "";
```

Posteriormente al dar clic y generar el `Toast`, almacena ese valor para usarlo en alguna otra parte.

Aquí también puedes agregar el valor a tu `TextView` , (suponiendo que tu `TextView` es `myTextView`), ejemplo:

```
 builder.setTitle("Estado Civil")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        valorSeleccionado = items[which];

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Seleccionaste: " + valorSeleccionado , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                              //Asigna valor a TextView
                               myTextView.setText(valorSeleccionado);

                    }
                })
```

Comment: disculpa me marca error en esta parte del codigo valorSeleccionado = items[which];y tambien a qui .show(); a que se debe

Comment: lo siento @luissantosmanceras tenía incorrecto el código, revisa nuevamente y me comentas resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Porque en vez de un toast no ocupas un SnackBar y el snackbar tiene un la funcionalidad de meter un boton y asi cuando le den tap al boton puedes pintar la info en tu textview
te dejo un ejemplo:

```
  Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        getString(R.string.carga_reparto),Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(getString(R.string.inicio_reparto), Evento_Accion)
                        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.azul_sec_tumsa))
                        .show();
```

Haces un metodo como este:

```
    private View.OnClickListener Evento_Accion = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Cerramos la app
        layoutReparto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AssistanceFragment nextFrag= new AssistanceFragment();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.containerFragment, nextFrag, "findThisFragment")
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
};
```

Solo cambia el comportamiento del metodo

Espero que te sirva